# Error using nativescript `tns run android`

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am very new to nativescript and just starting up a new project using nativescript. I am trying to run nativescript starter template using `tns run android` and its showing error saying `The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android.`

Can someone help me in fixing in this issue please?

Comment: Can you provide more info about your operating system? Also, did you managed to successfully complete the installation steps as described here: https://docs.nativescript.org/start/quick-setup?

Comment: @anthares I completed the setup without any errors. I am using Windows 8.

Comment: were you using the manual setup instructions or the Windows installer?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable on your machine is not created successfully. You can try to set it up manually, using the following PowerShell command:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ANDROID_HOME", "<Path to Android SDK>", "Machine")
```

You will need restart your console in order this to take effect. By the way, if you run `tns doctor`, it should tell you if there is a problem with your local setup.